# search in SQS queue with some keys in queue

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I want to search some specific data from queue so that the logged in user can only his queued notifications in my node application.

Actually i am new to SQS unable to find any solution.Anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

It is **not possible to retrieve specific messages** from an Amazon SQS (Simple Queueing Service) queue.

While messages can be given additional attributes (key-value pairs), **neither the attributes nor the content of a message can be used to selectively retrieve data**.

If you need to retrieve only a subset of queued data, some options are:

- Use a separate queue for each user
- Store the data in a database (eg DynamoDB or Amazon RDS) and query for the information
- Store the data as files in Amazon S3 within specific paths for each user and then look in those paths for data